# JavaFX / FXML add ChoiceBox to root Pane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

i have started programing in JavaFX.

My problem is that i dont really understand the connection between the scene builder and "normal" code.

I have a new FXML Document and a code like this

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

I can add some elements via Scene Builder. It works fine.
But now i want to add a ChoiceBox with some Values. I could add a blank ChoiceBox via Scene Builder. But without values...

So i find some code which creates a ChoiceBox with value

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();

        cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Eins","Zwei","Drei","vier"));

        cb.setValue("Zwei");
        cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                System.out.println(cb.getValue());
            }

        });
```

It works very fine too. But how can i add this to my scene? i think the following line of code doesnt work for me because my root element got a FMXLLoader

```
root.getChildren().add(cb);
```

I think you have the getChildren() Methode only if you are using something like this

```
AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
```

But then i have to code everything via code and nothing via Scene Builder. Is it right? Or is there a way to combine "normal" code and the scene builder features?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FXML is just a way to create a object structure. What you do with those objects after creation is entirely up to you. If you create a scene graph from fxml, you can do the same things with the `Node`s you could do with objects created from java code, including adding children to `Pane`s and setting the items of a `ChoiceBox`... Just inject the relevant nodes to the controller using the `fx:id` attribute and get your hands on the controller instance by using a `FXMLLoader` **instance** to load the fxml.

Example:

#### message.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxmltest.MessageController"> 
</VBox>
```

```
public class MessageController {
    
    @FXML
    private VBox root;

    public void addMessage(String message) {
        root.getChildren().add(new Label(message));
    }
    
}
```

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("message.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

MessageController controller = loader.getController();
controller.addMessage("Hello World");
controller.addMessage("42");
```